# React Query - refetch on window focus but not otherwise?

Tags: react-query

After having this question answered:
[React Query - query is not using cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70238846/react-query-query-is-not-using-cache/70294211#70294211)

I had another question - what if i want to refetch the data on window focus, but not otherwise?

If i change the `staleTime` to `Infinity` like suggested in the question above, React Query would never refetch on window focus.

Isn't it possible to never refetch, **unless** there's a window focus?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
staleTime: Infinity,
refetchOnWindowFocus: 'always'
```

`refetchOnWindowFocus` defaults to `true`, which will only refetch stale queries. Set it to `always` to, well, always refetch.

It's in the [api reference for useQuery](https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/useQuery).

Comment: Oh i guess i missed that, thank you :)